What are the CPU architectures for the most common general purpose devices (i.e., Android, Windows/Linux PC, RaspberryPi etc.)?
Wikipedia lists over 45 different Instruction Set Architectures.
I would bet that most of those are listed for legacy purposes, but I barely have any knowledge on the subject (I'm not even sure if ISAs directly correspond to architectures as in, e.g., amd64). It seems to be a topic "beyond my scope", and I have to Google the architecture for whatever device I'm dealing with, every single time.
Usually, I'm dealing with laptops and PCs (sometimes running Windows, sometimes OMV, which is based on Debian), Android devices (mostly smartphones), RaspberryPIs, and perhaps other SBCs in the future.
While I often see stuff such as ARM, ARMv7 ARMv8, x64, amd64, AArch64 and a few others, my research so far showed that many of them are references to a subset/family of architectures, so I end up wasting a lot of time to finally find that the answer was actually very simple.
I think I use this information almost exclusively for downloading the correct release of some software for my device (specially considering I'm only a beginner in using Docker).

Up until I started looking for this information, I didn't even know there was such a thing as RAM Architectures (per this question), so, if possible and relevant, I would appreciate any information on that as well!
Finally, I know that my question is derivative from this one and perhaps even others, but I felt like neither question I mentioned was aimed at what I this one intends to, as those and others are specific to some application of this concept (and often on StackOverflow)!

Edit: I believe I might have phrased my question incorrectly. With "the CPU architectures for the most common general purpose devices", I intended to ask for a summary of common architectures per "platform", such as:



Platform
Main architecture(s)
AKA
Included in/similar to




Android
arm64-v8a
?
?


 
armeabi
?
?


 
armeabi-v7a
?
?


 
x86_64
x64 (?)
?


 
x86
-
Included in x86_64


Windows
x64
amd64
Included in AMD Instruction Set, Similar to Intel Instruction Set


 
ARM A64
AArch64, ARM64
Included in Intel Instruction Set, Similar to AMD Instruction Set


Linux
(on a PC/laptop, is it even different from Windows?)
 
 


RaspberryPi
 
 
 


...
(is there anything else relevant for personal use?)
 
 



... and so on.
(Everything on the above table is based on @pjc50's answer and @Sarthak Mishra's answer to this question).

I don't know if this table should be shorter or longer, since I'm asking for a list of relevant items, although I don't even know how many architectures (relevant or not) are there. For this, I apologize if I'm asking way too much!

Most common at the moment are x64 (which is the same as x86_64 and amd64) and arm64 (which is the same as aarch64). Everything else is either older version or 32bit variant or very rare nieche.

How come the computer with the highest unit sales in the USA is not on your list?

@gnasher729 which one you refer to?

From software in user space, you basically don't have to care about RAM architecture.
There are approximately two CPU lines you need to care about, Intel/AMD vs ARM, each of which comes in a 32-bit and 64-bit flavor.
You may or may not decide to care about 32-bit architectures ("x86" and "ARM A32 aka ARMv1-9").
That leaves "x64" (the AMD64 instruction set) and "ARM A64 aka AArch64".
That covers about 90% of what you might need to know. You can see that Microsoft have their C# support for those, additionally spread across operating systems.
If you're going to emit machine code yourself, or rely on specific accelerator features, then it gets a lot more complicated and you need to know which of SSE, MMX, AVX, NEON etc applies and is currently available.

Hi, sorry for my late reply, I didn't intend to "abandon" the question like this. On your answer, I went back and rewrote a lot of my original question, it should be clearer now! Finally, I don't intend to emit machine code at all, I'm just trying to learn enough so I won't need to google every time I need to choose the proper version of some software/app!
